# Ajax load method does not load at top of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My site has a div where content is loaded using the Ajax load method.  When any of several links on the home page is clicked, another div on that page is loaded with the content from the selected url.  Here's the div:

```
<div class="main_text">
<div id="C2"><span style="color:black">MTX</span></div>
</div>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script>
function ShowAjax(type) {
    var filename = "text_" + type + ".htm"
    $( "#C2" ).hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
}
</script>
```

The problem is when I load a new page into a div using the AJAX script shown above, the new page doesn't always load at the top if I had scrolled down on a different page before loading the new page.

I would like the new content to load at the top of the div, not somewhere farther down the page.

I have tried two things so far.  The first one is calling scrollTop right after the load:

```
    $(" #C2 ").scrollTop();
```

The second one is a script at the top of each page to fire on document ready:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
    window.scroll(0,0);
    console.log("ready to scroll top");
});
</script>
```

The console.log shows in the dev console, but it doesn't scroll to the top or start at the top.

How can I get the pages to load with the Ajax load method and always appear at the top of the div, with the first line of the text showing instead of starting somewhere down the text (for example, starting on paragraph 3)?  Or alternatively how can I force it to scroll to the top after page load?

Comment: what do you mean by "on top of of the div"?

Comment: When the content loads, I want the content to load with the first line of the content showing.  As it is now, it may load with paragraph 3 showing at the top, forcing the user to scroll to the top.  That happens if I was on another page loaded into the div but scrolled down from the top.  The new content starts at the page coordinates I just left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you appear to be using [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) wrong.  Scrolltop with no argument tells you WHERE the scrollbar is on the element, if there is one.  Scrolltop with an argument of a height sets the scrollbar.  So $("#C2").scrollTop() would probably return 0 since the element probably has no scrollbar.  And since you never use the value, it wouldn't do anything.  You also probably want to change the scrollbar of the entire document.  In reality you would need something like this:

```
$(document).scrollTop( $(target).offset().top );
```

[Here is an example in jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qiqowid/edit?js,output).  Scroll down to the bottom to see the buttons to click, and then it will bring the document scroll to bring the target element to the top of the viewport.

- offset returns an object with top and left properties.  Giving the position of the element relative to the document.  .position gives the position relative to the parent.  Using that top number, you can then use that in scrollTop to change the position of the document.

  - scrollTop then takes that number (the top position of the element) and scrolls the document (or other element) to that position.

It also sounds to me like you are trying to make the element at the top of the page receive the content, regardless of which div was clicked?

If that's the case, then either directly select that element

```
$('#topElement').hide().load( filename ).fadeIn(500);
```

Or use one of the actual [ajax methods](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that load is the shortcut for, and target that element in the success callback

```
$.ajax({
  url: filename,
  success: function( response ){
    $("#topElement").hide().html(response).fadeIn(500);
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  I'm working with your ideas now and I'll post back after I've tried them.  The element does have a scrollbar.

Comment: One question: would $(document).scrollTop( $(target).position().top ); go at the top of the page being loaded (filename) or as a callback from the ajax load call?

Comment: jquery .position gives you an object with top and left.  It is also relative to the parent.  You may instead want to use .offset might actually be what you want, as that gives you the position from the top of the document.  It would then provide the location of the element, and scrolltop would move the target element's scrollbar to that position.  I've updated my answer to reflect offset being a better option.

Comment: Does $(document).scrollTop( $(target).position().top ); go to the page that is being loaded, or as a callback to the load method?  On other words, is it for the document.ready in the target page?

Comment: @RTC222 I've updated my answer with an example in jsbin, and given greater clarification to what the code does.

Comment: Thanks for the code section.  I need that to function automatically, not on a button click, so I will revise it to fit my situation and call it as a  document.ready function.